# System.NullReferenceException but the code works before

Tags: arrays, vb.net, visual-studio, null

I'm kinda new on the VB.Net. My problem is the code gives System.NullReferenceException. I don't know where's my fault, i've been looking for the whole code to find the mistakes for 2 hrs. Here's text file and code

E:\Source\Film\datastore.mdf

```
endgame Avengers:_End_Game_(2019) Indonesia Action_Adventure_Drama
ageofultron Avengers:_Age_of_Ultron_(2015) Indonesia Action_Adventure_Sci-Fi
```

On the Public Class section

```
Private ReadOnly Path As String = "E:\Source\Film\"
    Private Shared FolderData() As String
    Private Shared Title As String
    Private Shared Subtitle As String
    Private Shared Genre As String
```

And This on the Private Sub Section

```
        Dim FilmData(File.ReadAllLines(Path + "datastore.mdf").Length) As String
        Dim FileNum = FreeFile()
        FileOpen(FileNum, Path + "datastore.mdf", OpenMode.Input)
        Dim x As Integer = 0
        Do Until (EOF(FileNum))
            FilmData(x) = LineInput(FileNum)
            x += 1
        Loop
        FileClose(FileNum)

        If FilmData(0) IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim Data1() As String = FilmData(0).Split(New Char() {" "c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

            FolderData(0) = Data1(0)
            Title = Data1(1)
            Title = Title.Replace("_", " ")
            Subtitle = Data1(2)
            Genre = Data1(3)
            Genre = Genre.Replace("_", " ")
        End If
```

The Code gives me System.NullReferenceException on the
`Title = Data1(1)` line also the subtitle and genre too

Any solution or someone could find where's the cause? Any response and answer will be apreciated

Comment: Why `Split(New Char() {" "c}` ? Why not `Split("")` ?!!!!!

Comment: Data1 has only one entry. Hence you cannot access to Data1(1). Have you checked the size of Data1?

Comment: If this is a text file, why does it have and .mdf extension?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem was with `FolderData`. You declared it as `Private Shared FolderData() As String` but you did not give it a dimension. You cannot add items to an array with no dimension. Since we may not know the size of the array, I changed it to a `List(Of String)` and used the list's `.Add` method.

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim FilmData = File.ReadAllLines(Path.Combine(DataPath, "datastore.mdf"))
    If FilmData(0) IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim Data1 = FilmData(0).Split({" "c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        FolderData.Add(Data1(0))
        Title = Data1(1)
        Title = Title.Replace("_", " ")
        Subtitle = Data1(2)
        Genre = Data1(3)
        Genre = Genre.Replace("_", " ")
    End If
    Debug.Print($"The Folder Date is {FolderData(0)}")
    Debug.Print($"The Title is {Title}")
    Debug.Print($"The Subtitle is {Subtitle}")
    Debug.Print($"The Genre is {Genre}")
End Sub
```

The Immediate Window shows

```
The Folder Date is endgame
The Title is Avengers: End Game (2019)
The Subtitle is Indonesia
The Genre is Action Adventure Drama
```

I am not sure why your variables are declared as `Private Shared`. If they are private, they cannot be seen outside the class so, why would they be shared?